# anyone tell how is this effect created which change lips color to orange and little orange on face without brush etc tool

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image]

how to change the only lips color to orange without brush etc tool and how this is created and little orange on face

Comment: To me, it looks like make up the actors were wearing, then some tonal adjustments were made to the photos. The orange wasn't added to the photos, merely enhanced by adjustments.

Comment: It looks like the images were run through a filter IMO

Comment: where i find imo filter

Comment: IMO = In My Opinion. It's not a filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell exactly how it was created. Since you don't have an original to compare it against, it's difficult to tell how much the colours have been changed.  However, I can tell you how I would create something similar.

1. Add a Hue-Saturation adjustment layer, then select the mask and use the Colour Range selector, select the lips. Change the hue until it's orange, and increase the saturation to make it more vibrant.
2. Add another Hue-Saturation adjustment layer, then select the mask and the Colour Range selector, this time select the skin. Reduce the saturation. Increase the feathering of the selection. You might need to touch up the mask using the paintbrush to modify it slightly. I had to do this to bring some colour back to the cheeks.
3. As for creating the lined/definition effect, one possibility is to use the Topaz Studio plug-in, which is free. Then you can add a Smudge filter using the "liquid lines" preset. Alternatively you could simply use Photoshop's own Oil Paint filter to get a similar look.
4. Finally add an Exposure adjustment layer to brighten the image.

Example

[image]

Comment: @MindlessChaudhry: Please note that we do not like to do your work for free here. We can show you the way, but you have to walk it on your own. We also do not do video tutorials on demand.